# cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'MyElement'

Tags: xsd, xml-namespaces, xml-validation, xml-error

I'm trying to validate a really simple xml using xsd, but for some reason I get this error.
I'll really appreciate if someone can explain me why.

*XML File*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<MyElement>A</MyElement>
```

*XSD File*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/Test"
        xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/Test"
        elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <simpleType name="MyType">
        <restriction base="string"></restriction>
    </simpleType>

    <element name="MyElement" type="tns:MyType"></element>
</schema>
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Your schema is for its target namespace `http://www.example.org/Test` so it defines an element with name `MyElement` in that target namespace `http://www.example.org/Test`. Your instance document however has an element with name `MyElement` in **no namespace**. That is why the validating parser tells you it can't find a declaration for that element, you haven't provided a schema for elements in no namespace.

You either need to change the schema to not use a target namespace at all or you need to change the instance to use e.g. `<MyElement xmlns="http://www.example.org/Test">A</MyElement>`.

Answer (score 8):

After making the change suggested above by Martin, I was still getting the same error. I had to make an additional change to my parsing code. I was parsing the XML file via a DocumentBuilder as shown in the oracle docs:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/package-summary.html

```
// parse an XML document into a DOM tree
DocumentBuilder parser = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = parser.parse(new File("example.xml"));
```

The problem was that DocumentBuilder is not namespace aware by default. The following additional change resolved the issue:

```
// parse an XML document into a DOM tree
DocumentBuilderFactory dmfactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dmfactory.setNamespaceAware(true);

DocumentBuilder parser = dmfactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = parser.parse(new File("example.xml"));
```

Comment: dmfactory.setNamespaceAware(true); Was misssed out when we were migrating old project from Java 8 to JAVA 11 + . Thankyou this works.

Answer (score 2):

I had this error for my XXX element and it was because my XSD was wrongly formatted according to javax.xml.bind v2.2.11 . I think it's using an older XSD format but I didn't bother to confirm.

My initial wrong XSD was alike the following:

```
<xs:element name="Document" type="Document"/>
...
<xs:complexType name="Document">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="XXX" type="XXX_TYPE"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

The good XSD format for my migration to succeed was the following:

```
<xs:element name="Document">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="XXX"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>        
</xs:element>
...
<xs:element name="XXX" type="XXX_TYPE"/>
```

And so on for every similar XSD nodes.

Answer (score 1):

I got this same error working in Eclipse with Maven with the additional information

```
schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
```

This was after copying in a new controller and it's interface from a Thymeleaf example. Honestly, no matter how careful I am I still am at a loss to understand how one is expected to figure this out. On a (lucky) guess I right clicked the project, clicked Maven and Update Project which cleared up the issue.

Answer (score 0):

To expand upon the top answer. If you're using Java Web Services (JAX-WS) annotations to define your services, like in this example:

```
@WebService(..., targetNamespace = "http://bar.foo.com/")
```

Then make sure that your SOAP request has exactly the same namespace as defined in your annotation:

```
<soapenv:Envelope 
   xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
   xmlns:foo="http://bar.foo.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <foo:someRequest>
          ...
      </foo:someRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The `targetNamespace` in your annotation and the `xmlns:foo` property in the XML request must match! Literally every character (including whitespace) must match. Also don't forget to put the `/` at the end as well (it's a very common mistake).