# cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'xxx'

Tags: xml, xsd

I have to handwriting an sample xml for my xsd, but I always get invalid message: **cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'RS_WMS_GET_PO_DATA_v2.0'.**

My XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<schema xmlns:ns0="http://www.rossinc.com/" xmlns:msbtsdml="http://schemas.rossinc.com/BizTalk" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.rossinc.com/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <annotation>
    <appinfo>
      <msbtsdml:StoredProcedureName xmlns:msbtsdml="http://schemas.rossinc.com/BizTalk/DMLAdapter">RS_WMS_GET_PO_DATA</msbtsdml:StoredProcedureName>
      <msbtsdml:ResponseRootName xmlns:msbtsdml="http://schemas.rossinc.com/BizTalk/DMLAdapter">poData</msbtsdml:ResponseRootName>
    </appinfo>
  </annotation>
  <element name="RS_WMS_GET_PO_DATA_v2.0">
    <complexType>
      <sequence>
        <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Parameters">
          <complexType>
            <sequence>
              <element default="0" name="ERROR_OCCURRED" type="string">
                <annotation>
                  <appinfo>
                    <msbtsdml:ParamDir xmlns:msbtsdml="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003">In</msbtsdml:ParamDir>
                  </appinfo>
                </annotation>
              </element>
              <element default="1" name="XML_TAGS" type="int">
                <annotation>
                  <appinfo>
                    <msbtsdml:ParamDir xmlns:msbtsdml="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003">In</msbtsdml:ParamDir>
                  </appinfo>
                </annotation>
              </element>
              <element default="0" name="NUM_ROWS" type="int">
                <annotation>
                  <appinfo>
                    <msbtsdml:ParamDir xmlns:msbtsdml="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003">In</msbtsdml:ParamDir>
                  </appinfo>
                </annotation>
              </element>
            </sequence>
          </complexType>
        </element>
        <element name="RS_WMS_GET_PO_DATA">
          <complexType>
            <all minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
              <element name="COMPANY_CODE" type="string" />
              <element name="DIVISION" type="string" />
              <element name="PO_NUMBER" type="string" />
              <element name="PO_WH_SEQUENCE" type="string" />
              <element name="ERP_ACTION_CODE" type="string" />
            </all>
          </complexType>
        </element>
        <element name="DMLAdapterConfig">
          <complexType>
            <sequence>
              <element name="EnvironmentId" type="string" />
            </sequence>
          </complexType>
        </element>
      </sequence>
    </complexType>
  </element>
</schema>
```

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RS_WMS_GET_PO_DATA_v2.0>
    <Parameters>
        <ERROR_OCCURRED>0</ERROR_OCCURRED>
        <XML_TAGS>1</XML_TAGS>
        <NUM_ROWS>0</NUM_ROWS>
    </Parameters>
    <RS_WMS_GET_PO_DATA>
        <COMPANY_CODE></COMPANY_CODE>
        <DIVISION></DIVISION>
        <PO_NUMBER></PO_NUMBER>
        <PO_WH_SEQUENCE></PO_WH_SEQUENCE>
        <ERP_ACTION_CODE></ERP_ACTION_CODE>
    </RS_WMS_GET_PO_DATA>
    <DMLAdapterConfig>
        <EnvironmentId></EnvironmentId>
    </DMLAdapterConfig>
</RS_WMS_GET_PO_DATA_v2.0>
```

Any ideas?

Here's the website I'm using:
http://www.corefiling.com/opensource/schemaValidate.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'MyElement'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13310637/cvc-elt-1-cannot-find-the-declaration-of-element-myelement)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:RS_WMS_GET_PO_DATA_v2.0 xmlns:ns0="http://www.rossinc.com/"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.rossinc.com/ One.xsd ">
<ns0:Parameters>
<ns0:ERROR_OCCURRED>0</ns0:ERROR_OCCURRED>
<ns0:XML_TAGS>1</ns0:XML_TAGS>
<ns0:NUM_ROWS>0</ns0:NUM_ROWS>
</ns0:Parameters>
<ns0:RS_WMS_GET_PO_DATA>
<ns0:COMPANY_CODE>ns0:COMPANY_CODE</ns0:COMPANY_CODE>
<ns0:DIVISION>ns0:DIVISION</ns0:DIVISION>
<ns0:PO_NUMBER>ns0:PO_NUMBER</ns0:PO_NUMBER>
<ns0:PO_WH_SEQUENCE>ns0:PO_WH_SEQUENCE</ns0:PO_WH_SEQUENCE>
<ns0:ERP_ACTION_CODE>ns0:ERP_ACTION_CODE</ns0:ERP_ACTION_CODE>
</ns0:RS_WMS_GET_PO_DATA>
<ns0:DMLAdapterConfig>
<ns0:EnvironmentId>ns0:EnvironmentId</ns0:EnvironmentId>
</ns0:DMLAdapterConfig>
</ns0:RS_WMS_GET_PO_DATA_v2.0>
```

As because you did not mentioned which schema file to use for this XML file. I think tis will solve your problem.

Comment: tried again,but failed.   Error:Content is not allowed in prolog.

Comment: how you are validating it. I created the XSD given by you in the question and created an XML based on that using Eclipse.

Comment: use [this](http://www.xmlvalidation.com/?L=0) link to validate xml over xsd online. Check the `Validate against external XML schema` check box and then copy the xml file in the text box. Once you click on the Validate button it will ask you to copy XSD as it is referred in the xml file.

Comment: Yeah,it passed, but, how weird? The approach of my schema validation site is different than yours? @Joshi

Answer (score 4):

I had an error

> cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element problem!

I solved it this way:

1. Look for your XSD file, if it has a `xmlns` attribute, for instance:

   ```
   xmlns="http://yourcompany/blablabla/rootElementName"
   ```
2. Look into your XML file, it must have an `xmlns` attribute if the XSD has defined one.

   ```
   <rootElement xmlns="http://company/xxxxxx/rootElementName">
   ```
3. XML is case sensitive. Review your XML tags and compare them with the XSD tags.

Regards!