# Unable to marshal JAXB object due to SAXParseException (Cannot find the declaration of element error)

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I am trying to validate an XML. The XML has the root element as "Notifications" and list of "Customers".
I want to validate each customer against the XSD and in case the validation fails I want to
print the Customer Id element value and error message. Currently in the application all the data is available as JAXB objects.
I am using JAXB marshaller to marshall the Customer object which may return error if the validation fails.
However the marshalling call is throwing below error.

**Error Message:**

```
MESSAGE:  cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'Customer'.
LINKED EXCEPTION:  org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 0; columnNumber: 0; cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'Customer'.
```

Below are the snippets of XSD, XML and marshalling code.

**XSD** (cutdown version)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsd:schema
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
  elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.company1.uk/schemas/app1"
  version="4.03" xmlns="http://www.company1.uk/schemas/app1">
  <xsd:element name="Notifications">
        <xsd:element name="Header">..</xsd:element>
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Customers">
              <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Customer">
              ..
              </xsd:element>
```

**XML** (cutdown version)

```
<Notifications>
  <Header>
  ..
  </Header>
  <Customers>
    <Customer>
      <Id>1</Id>
      ..
    </Customer>
    <Customer>
      <Id>2</Id>
      ..
    </Customer>
  </Customers>
</Notifications>
```

**JAXB Classes**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "header",
    "customers"
})
```

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Notifications", namespace = "http://www.company1.uk/schemas/app1")
public class Notifications {
```

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
 @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
     "customer"
 })
 public static class Customers {
```

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "customerDetails",
    "transactions"
})
public static class Customer {
```

** Code to marshall or validate objects/elements **

```
  public static void validateObjectWithXSD(final Customer customer)
      throws IOException, SAXException, URISyntaxException, JAXBException {

    final SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    schemaFactory.setProperty(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_SCHEMA, "file");
    schemaFactory.setProperty(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD, "file");
    //LocalResourceResolver implements org.w3c.dom.ls.LSResourceResolver
    final LocalResourceResolver resourceResolver = LocalResourceResolver.create("xsd");
    schemaFactory.setResourceResolver(resourceResolver);

    final Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema();

    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(customer.getClass());

    Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setEventHandler(new CustomValidationEventHandler());

    marshaller.setSchema(schema);
    marshaller.marshal(new JAXBElement<>(new QName("http://www.company1.uk/schemas/app1", "Customer"), Customer.class, customer), System.out);

  }
```

Comment: Can you confirm that targetNamespace is the same in xsd and xml?

Comment: Hi @Isma, Thanks for your response. My understanding is that if we are unmarshalling/validating an XML then we need the targetNamespace to match in XSD and XML.  However in my case I am trying to marshal the objects to XML and it is failing to convert/marshal the JAXB objects to XML due to the above mentioned error. I have defined the QName for the Customer element as "new QName("http://www.company1.uk/schemas/app1", "Customer")". Not sure if this sufficient or correct. Looks like with the given information it could not relate the Customer object with the definition in the XSD.

Comment: Please note that I have included a sample XML in the actual ticket to make it is easy to comprehend the XML structure.