# How to achieve security level 3 in FIWARE?

Tags: security, authorization, access-control, fiware, xacml

I am deploying FIWARE security GEs (i.e., Wilma, AuthzForce, Keyrock) in my computer. Security level 2 (Basic Authorization) is working well, but now I need security level 3 (Advanced Authorization) using XACML.

Long story short, I want a tutorial of implementation security level 3. However, as far as I know, any tutorial or document about security level 3 does not exist.

For now, I create my policy with PAP's API, and change 'custom_policy' option in config.js from 'undefined' to 'policy.js'. And then I create 'policy.js' file into 'PEP/policies', but don't change anything compared with its template file because I don't know what this code does exactly. I think I should make XACML Request form using 'xml' variable. But in my case, PEP gives me the error when I make the XACML Request using 'xml' variable, and return this variable. Here is my error of PEP:

```
Error: Root - Error in AZF communication <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><error xmlns="http://authzforce.github.io/rest-api-model/xmlns/authz/S" xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:ns3="http://authzforce.github.io/core/xmlns/pdp/5.0" xmlns:ns4="http://authzforce.github.io/pap-dao-flat-file/xmlns/properties/3.6"><message>Invalid parameters: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'Request'.</message></error>
```

And here is my 'getPolicy' code (XACML Request) in policy.js. I just made very simple request whether response is permit or not because I'm not sure what I'm doing at that time.:

```
exports.getPolicy = function (roles, req, app_id) {
    var xml = xmlBuilder.create('Request', {
            'xmlns': 'urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17',
            'CombinedDecision': 'false',
            'ReturnPolicyIdList': 'false'})
    .ele('Attributes', {
            'Category': 'urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject'});
```

So, anyone can give me any information about implementation of security level 3?

Comment: Which version of Wilma are you using?

Comment: Keyrock is 5.4.1, Wilma is 5.4 and AuthzForce is 5.4.1 now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrade to Wilma 6.2 (bug fixing).

Reuse the code from [lib/azf.js](https://github.com/ging/fiware-pep-proxy/blob/master/lib/azf.js#L94) which is known to work, and adapt the Request content to your needs. The variable is wrongly called `XACMLPolicy` there, but don't be mistaken, this is an actual XACML `Request`. This is using `xml2json` package to convert the JSON to XML, whereas in your code you seem to use a different one, `xmlbuilder` maybe? You didn't paste the full code - where does this `xmlBuilder` variable come from? - so I'm just guessing.

If you are indeed using `xmlbuilder` package and want to stick with it, I notice that in the [example using namespaces](https://github.com/oozcitak/xmlbuilder-js/wiki/Examples), the xmlns attribute is put in a different way:

```
var xmlBuilder = require('xmlbuilder');

var xml = xmlBuilder.create('Request', { encoding: 'utf-8' })
.att('xmlns', 'urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17')
.att('CombinedDecision': 'false')
.att('ReturnPolicyIdList': 'false')
.ele('Attributes', {'Category': 'urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject'});
```

Maybe this makes a difference, I didn't check.

Also feel free to create an issue with your question on [Wilma's github](https://github.com/ging/fiware-pep-proxy/issues) to get help from the dev team. (I am not one of them but we've worked together for AuthzForce integration.)

Comment: Wow, Thanks for your answer. I will try this later. And I have one more question. There is XACML section when I create permission in Keyrock (below verb+path section), what is it? I need to write something in the section to achieve level 3?

Comment: Is the section title only "XACML" or "XACML rule"? This should be where you can write a XACML Rule manually (without xmlns stuff), e.g. `<Rule RuleId="custom-rule" Effect="Permit">...</Rule>`. It will be combined with the other permissions. Every one in verb+path form is converted to a XACML Rule (cf. [conversion  templates](https://github.com/ging/horizon/tree/master/openstack_dashboard/templates/access_control) ).

Comment: In the end, you get one XACML Rule per permission, one <Policy> per role (combining all those Rules); and one <PolicySet> for the application (combining all those <Policy>s); and this PolicySet is the piece that is sent to AuthzForce.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is really

> Invalid parameters: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element
>   'Request'.

This is a simple XML validation issue. You need to make sure that the XACML request you send contains the right namespace declaration.

You'll see there is another question on this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13310637/cvc-elt-1-cannot-find-the-declaration-of-element-myelement).

Can you paste your XACML request so we can tell whether it is valid?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I edited my content, and I will check your advice.