# SAXReader read() method throws org.dom4j.DocumentException when update from dom4j 1.6.1 to 2.0.3

Tags: dom4j

We updated dom4j from 1.6.1 to 2.0.3, Now we are getting following exception in parsing xml file

Our code is

```
SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
final SAXReader reader = new SAXReader(parser.getXMLReader());
reader.setValidation(false);
final InputSource source = new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlData));
final Document document = reader.read(source);
```

Error is

```
Error parsing xml data; nested exception is org.dom4j.DocumentException: Error on line 3 of document  : cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'users'. org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Error parsing xml data; nested exception is org.dom4j.DocumentException: Error on line 3 of document  : cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'users'.
    
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: Error on line 3 of document  : cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'users'.
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:511)
```

We refer
[text](https://github.com/dom4j/dom4j/issues/91)
and tried by set
saxParserFactory.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities", true);
saxParserFactory.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-parameter-entities", true);

and also we tried explicitly set all dependencies like Jaxen, xsdlib
But nothing Help,

Comment: You should edit the relevant parts of your xml and xsd into your question to be able to diagnose the problem, but maybe the issue is something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/50535565/?